# Key exchange using ECDH vs ECIES?

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-exchange, ecies

I'm a beginner to ECC crypto programming. Can anyone explain to me the difference between using ECDH for shared key exchange and the use of ECIES by encrypting a shared key with the public key of the receiver?

I feel that ECIES could also provide me with secure key exchange as long as the private key is kept secret.

Comment: "Normal" DH is an *online* two-party interaction, where the initiator needs to wait for the responder to correspond before they can derive the key to encipher the message.  IES is an *offline* scheme where the sender can carry out all their actions without waiting for the recipient to correspond.

Comment: I think this q is coming from the perspective of someone trying to understand why crypto p2p protocols use ECIES to deliver yet further ECDH session keys, and I think Conrads comment below answers it. Forward secrecy.

Answer (score 13):

That's a bit of a strange question. ECDH is a key agreement protool. ECC does not have a direct form of encryption as RSA has. ECIES is basically ECDH used to derive a symmetric key, which is then used to encrypt the plaintext. You can see it as a delayed form of key agreement.

So your question is if ECIES can be used to encrypt session keys. That would come down to performing ECDH to derive a data key, and then using that data key to encrypt a session key. Yes, it is probably secure, but directly deriving a session key using ECDH is a lot easier. Using ECIES is only useful if - for some reason or other - authenticated DH key establishment cannot be integrated into a protocol.

For more information about using ECIES & ECDH for authentication, please see [this other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83587/1172).

Comment: With ECDH is also possible to get forward secrecy (if the private key is compromised it won't be possible to decrypt previous messages)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79453/discussion-on-answer-by-maarten-bodewes-key-exchange-using-ecdh-vs-ecies) upon user request via mod flag.